# How do I use Paul Irish's Conditional comments in a SharePoint 2010 master page

Tags: sharepoint, html, master-pages, boilerplate

I want to use Paul Irish's Conditional comments from the Boilerplate HTML template:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

in a SharePoint 2010 masterpage. I have read 'conditional comments don’t always work so well in SP2010'. (not sure what that means!) The advice is to use:

```
<SharePoint:CSSRegistration Name="foo.css" ConditionalExpression="gte IE 7" runat="server" />
```

This allows me to use a conditional to load a specific stylesheet but not to use the Conditional html tag in the way Paul Irish suggests. Is there a way to do this or can I just simply paste the code from Biolerplate into the Sharepoint masterpage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am very new to SharePoint branding and was coming across the same problem. I am not a ASP developer so understanding some of the solutions were a little tough.

What I did was take Paul's conditional statements with the HTML tag and moved them to the BODY tag and it seemed to work just perfect with out having to mess with and SP code.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <body class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" scroll="no" onload="javascript:_spBodyOnLoadWrapper();"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <body class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" scroll="no" onload="javascript:_spBodyOnLoadWrapper();"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <body class="no-js lt-ie9" scroll="no" onload="javascript:_spBodyOnLoadWrapper();"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <body class="no-js" scroll="no" onload="javascript:_spBodyOnLoadWrapper();"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that the SharePoint masterpages equal the ones in ASP.NET (MVC). Therefore this shouln't be a problem at all.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
```

All the preceding code does is setting the HTML tag with a different CSS class on the HTML tag depending which browser is accessing the site. So that you are able to override some style sheets for any given browser (IE).

```
site.css

.coloredBackground
{
    background-color: #FF0000; //red
}
.ie6 .coloredBackground
{
    background-color: #00FF00; //green
}
.ie8 .coloredBackground
{
    background-color: #0000FF; //blue
}
```

In this example users browsing with Firefox, Opera, Safari, IE7,9,10 will see a red background. For IE6 the background color gets overridden with green and in IE8 with blue.

Your CSS registration would look like the following:

```
<SharePoint:CSSRegistration Name="site.css" runat="server" />
```

As you can see there is no need to set the ConditionalExpression anymore in the CSS registration, because you are already switching the used style sheet by setting a specific class on the HTML element.

**Update:**

Another possibility would be to include another style sheet file depending on the browser version using the ConditionalExpression property on the SharePoint aspx control.

```
<SharePoint:CSSRegistration Name="ie6.css" ConditionalExpression="lt IE 7" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:CSSRegistration Name="ie7.css" ConditionalExpression="IE 7" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:CSSRegistration Name="ie8.css" ConditionalExpression="IE 8" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:CSSRegistration Name="ie9.css" ConditionalExpression="IE 9" runat="server" />
```

The downside is that you may get css priority issues because the `.ie*` class is missing on the html element and therefore doesn't overrule the `.class-to-override-if-specific-ie-version`. You could solve this by using the `!important` rule in the ie specific style sheet files.

Comment: Yes, I know this is how it works - however Sharepoint 2010 strips out the conditional comment around the html tag so the css has no class to hook into.

Comment: Updated the answer with another possibility. It might not be the best solution but it should work...

Comment: Hi Diermo, thanks for putting in a lot of effort in your answers. Your update code will work but requires me to run separate css files for each IE version. The problem is that SharePoint strips out the conditional comments unless they are in the format used in your update. I want to know if I can use the Paul Irish style conditional comments in SharePoint? I know I can use SharePoint:CSSRegistration conditional expressions but this is not what I want. My question is: How do I use Paul Irish's Conditional comments in a SharePoint 2010 master page?

Answer (score 2):

*Posting again as my first reply was deleted. This has been edited to better meet StackOverflow's posting guidelines.*

I used this (from the bottom of Paul's post, dated 2012/1/17) and it worked fine in a SharePoint master page. Please note this is different than what you posted, which was an earlier version of the code.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

My concern is the other things that had to get stripped out that may be needed by SharePoint pages. Here is the original SharePoint HTML tag:

```
<html lang="<%$Resources:wss,language_value%>" dir="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_direction_dir_value%>" runat="server" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" __expr-val-dir="ltr">
```

Once you start adding that stuff in the HTML tags with the conditional comments the page breaks.

I urge you to also review your HTML/CSS to see if some of the conditional CSS can be removed to help streamline your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I used ASP literal strings to pass the conditional IE comments in my SP2010 masterpage.

That way, I could still pass in the language value used in the original `<html>` tag, `<%$Resources:wss,language_value%>`.

```
&lt;asp:literal ID=&quot;html1a&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot; Text=&quot;&amp;lt;!--[if lt IE 7]&amp;gt; &amp;lt;html class=&amp;quot;no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7&amp;quot; lang=&amp;quot;&quot;/&gt;&lt;asp:Literal ID=&quot;html1b&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot; Text=&quot;&lt;%$Resources:wss,language_value%&gt;&quot; /&gt;&lt;asp:literal ID=&quot;html1c&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot; Text=&quot;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;![endif]--&amp;gt;&quot;/&gt;<br />
&lt;asp:literal ID=&quot;html2a&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot; Text=&quot;&amp;lt;!--[if IE 7]&amp;gt;&amp;lt;html class=&amp;quot;no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8&amp;quot; lang=&amp;quot;&quot;/&gt;&lt;asp:Literal ID=&quot;html2b&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot; Text=&quot;&lt;%$Resources:wss,language_value%&gt;&quot; /&gt;&lt;asp:literal ID=&quot;html2c&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot; Text=&quot;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;![endif]--&amp;gt;&quot;/&gt;<br />
&lt;asp:literal ID=&quot;html3a&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot; Text=&quot;&amp;lt;!--[if IE 8]&amp;gt;&amp;lt;html class=&amp;quot;no-js lt-ie9&amp;quot; lang=&amp;quot;&quot;/&gt;&lt;asp:Literal ID=&quot;html3b&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot; Text=&quot;&lt;%$Resources:wss,language_value%&gt;&quot; /&gt;&lt;asp:literal ID=&quot;html3c&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot; Text=&quot;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;![endif]--&amp;gt;&quot;/&gt;<br />
&lt;asp:literal ID=&quot;html4a&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot; Text=&quot;&amp;lt;!--[if gt IE 8]&amp;gt;&amp;lt;!--&amp;gt; &amp;lt;html class=&amp;quot;no-js&amp;quot; lang=&amp;quot;&quot;/&gt;&lt;asp:Literal ID=&quot;html4b&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot; Text=&quot;&lt;%$Resources:wss,language_value%&gt;&quot; /&gt;&lt;asp:literal ID=&quot;html4c&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot; Text=&quot;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;!--&amp;lt;![endif]--&amp;gt;&quot;/&gt;
```

But if someone could further improve this method, it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With Sharepoint 2010 it is best to avoid putting conditionals around the `<html>` tag. That being said, you can add in your conditionals within the `<head>` tag and add classes to your html tag using Javascript. This is not ideal for a regular website but for Sharepoint, this is an unubtrusive method that works in a large enterprise Sharepoint 2010 site that I help maintain:

```
...
<html id="Html1" class="no-js" lang="<%$Resources:wss,language_value %>" dir="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_direction_dir_value %>" runat="server" __expr-val-dir="ltr">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!-- IE version conditionals will apply classes to html element if old IE -->
        <!--[if lt IE 7 ]><script type="text/javascript">var element = document.getElementById("ctl00_Html1"); element.className += " " + "lt-ie7";</script><![endif]-->
        <!--[if lt IE 8 ]><script type="text/javascript">var element = document.getElementById("ctl00_Html1"); element.className += " " + "lt-ie8";</script><![endif]-->
        <!--[if lt IE 9 ]><script type="text/javascript">var element = document.getElementById("ctl00_Html1"); element.className += " " + "lt-ie9";</script><![endif]-->
        <!--[if lt IE 10 ]><script type="text/javascript">var element = document.getElementById("ctl00_Html1"); element.className += " " + "lt-ie10";</script><![endif]-->  
        ...
```