# Two inline-block, width 50% elements wrap to second line

Tags: html, css

I would like to have two columns of 50% width space, and avoid floats.
So i thought using `display:inline-block`.

When the elements add to 99% width (eg 50%, 49%, http://jsfiddle.net/XCDsu/2/ ) it works as expected.

When using 100% width (eg 50%, 50%, http://jsfiddle.net/XCDsu/3/ ) the second column breaks to the second line.

Why is that?

Comment: This question should be reopened since it is not a duplicate of the question about whitespace. This question seems more related to how to avoid the wrapping of the second 50% width element.

Comment: I guess this question is locked now so I can't add another answer. The easiest solution is to set `font-size: 0` on the inline-block elements, and then give the content of those elements a font size, e.g. `font-size: 16px`. This will remove the whitespace between them.

Answer (score 318, accepted):

It is because `display:inline-block` takes into account white-space in the html. If you remove the white-space between the `div`'s it works as expected. Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XCDsu/4/

```
<div id="col1">content</div><div id="col2">content</div>
```

Comment: It still won't work in IE7, though. Any ideas how to fix it there? Currently I make the elements of a fixed height (they are two buttons) and position them absolute with the left one having `right: 50%` and the right one having `left: 50%`. Not very elegant but works in every browser. :/

Comment: @panzi My suggestion below will solve your IE7 woes, and wont require you to remove whitespace from your HTML, which is a pain, and hard to eradicate from dynamic situations without a post-processor which costs more CPU-time for marginal bandwidth savings.

Comment: @Replete It's generated in JavaScript, so it's easy to prevent the white spaces. However, the layout changed so that I don't have such columns anyway.

Comment: sounds so stupid when you read it... and it does the trick ! amazing this still behaves like this after css3, because it sounds to me like a bug

Answer (score 123):

You can remove the whitespaces via css using **white-space** so you can keep your pretty HTML layout. Don't forget to set the white-space back to normal again if you want your text to wrap inside the columns.

Tested in IE9, Chrome 18, FF 12

```
.container { white-space: nowrap; }
.column { display: inline-block; width: 50%; white-space: normal; }

<div class="container">
  <div class="column">text that can wrap</div>
  <div class="column">text that can wrap</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using no-wrap makes the columns sit next to each other, but creates an undesirable padding, breaking out of the container. 

**My suggestion below does not have this issue**, here's a live example: http://jsbin.com/openuh/2

Comment: @Replete is it just me or does not appear to work with font-sizes defined in em's?

Comment: This solution is even better to have a cleaner HTML in dev mode at least :D

Comment: @PhilRicketts does this method not allow you to set a fixed height on the container? I tried and it does not work nor with the children.

Comment: nowrap seemed good, but it breaks in for some cases (not sure why, two 50% divs in a table cell, with nowrap, the 2nd div is displayed outside the cell). With just removing the space between divs (as per tw16's answer), it works...

Comment: This works perfectly!

Answer (score 36):

> **NOTE:** In 2016, you can probably use `flexbox` to solve this problem easier.

This method works correctly IE7+ and all major browsers, it's been tried and tested in a number of complex viewport-based web applications.

```
<style>
    .container {
        font-size: 0;
    }

    .ie7 .column {
        font-size: 16px; 
        display: inline; 
        zoom: 1;
    }

    .ie8 .column {
        font-size:16px;
    }

    .ie9_and_newer .column { 
        display: inline-block; 
        width: 50%; 
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="column">text that can wrap</div>
    <div class="column">text that can wrap</div>
</div>
```

**Live demo: [http://output.jsbin.com/sekeco/2](http://jsbin.com/sekeco/2)**

The only downside to this method for IE7/8, is relying on `body {font-size:??px}` as basis for em/%-based font-sizing.

IE7/IE8 specific CSS could be served using IE's [Conditional comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658113/how-do-i-use-paul-irishs-conditional-comments-in-a-sharepoint-2010-master-page)

Comment: This method is more practical since you can't always control the markup, especially if it is generated. Great solution!

Comment: This approach doesn't scale if markup changes to have 3 divs. inline-block keeps rows of 2 50% div and flex arranges all of them in a row, making them smaller. I however agree that this isn't the scenario in the OP's asked question.

Answer (score 14):

`inline` and `inline-block` elements are affected by whitespace in the HTML.

The simplest way to fix your problem is to remove the whitespace between `</div>` and `<div id="col2">`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/XCDsu/15/

There are other possible solutions, see: [bikeshedding CSS3 property alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350218/bikeshedding-css3-property-alternative/6351697#6351697)

Answer (score -2):

I continued to have this problem in ie7 when the browser was at certain widths. Turns out older browsers round the pixel value up if the percentage result isn't a whole number. To solve this you can try setting

```
overflow: hidden;
```

on the last element (or all of them).