# inline-block div wraps with width=50% and some text in it

Tags: html, css

Please look at this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPatf/5/)**.

I have different behavior for following two classes.

```css
.class2 {
    width: 49.5%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.class3 {
    width: 50%;    /* Wraps to next line */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

- What I wanted to do is to divide the width equally b/w two divs and then start filling each div * with its own content.
- But with width 50%, if I put some text in the div, the second div wraps to next line
- With width 49.x%, it does not wrap.

Why is it wrapping? I am working inside a particualr div.

How can I make it not wrap and keep width = 50%.

Other than 50%, I dont know how to come-up with the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `float: left;` to float you 1st `<div>` on the left and you can also float your 2nd `<div>` on the right using `float: right;` than use `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` to clear your floating elements:

**CSS**:

```css
.class1 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
}
.class2 {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    float: left;
}

.class3 {
background-color: green;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
      This is demo
  </div>
      <div class="class3">
          This is demo          
    </div>
  <div style="clear: both;">
</div>
```

[**My fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PPatf/8/)

Comment: would you be able to tell why floating solves the problem? I am trying it.

Comment: I guess this [**article**](http://designshack.net/articles/css/everything-you-never-knew-about-css-floats/) will help you in detail..

Answer (score 1):

Try floating your divs like this:

```
.class1 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;    
}
.class2 {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    float:left;    
}
.class3 {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to resort to `float`.  That is a relatively ugly workaround that introduces its own problem (having to clear floats and/or set `overflow:hidden` on the containing element).

You do not provide your HTML markup but I would guess you have whitespace between the elements, as in Mr Alien's answer.

See [Two inline-block, width 50% elements wrap to second line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871996/css-two-inline-block-width-50-elements-dont-stack) for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that they stack instead of sit next to one another is that display: inline-block recognizes white space. If you have a return after your first div, then it will pick that up and cause it to stack. A work around would be something similar to...

```
<div class="col1">

Column one content.

</div><div class="col2">

Column two content.

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use floats, they cause all sorts of headaches. Just add this to your CSS:

```
body,html{ white-space:nowrap; }
a,pre,p,span,strong,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{ white-space:normal; }
```

...then make sure all text on your site is contained either within 'p' or 'span'

Answer (score 0):

I often use **display:inline-block;** .

However, **display:inline-block** has some problem.

I recommend [Grids - Pure](http://purecss.io/grids/) pattern and wrote a sample code like Pure.

```
.class1 {
    letter-spacing: -0.31em;
    *letter-spacing: normal;
    *word-spacing: -0.43em;
    text-rendering: optimizespeed;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
}

.class2, .class3 {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-rendering: auto;
    font-family: "Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN",Meiryo,Verdana,sans-serif;
    width: 50%;
}
```

[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2NkQV/3/)

Answer (score -1):

Put a:

```
margin:-2px;
```

into your class3.
This doesn't break your div but solve your problem.
Don't know why