# Place divs side by side in twitter bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a twitter bootstrap carousel with one item in it `div with id="world_recipes"`. Within that item are two divs that I would like to place side by side `div class="description"` and `div class="proj_image"`. I tried applying float: left; to the child divs but that did not work.

```
<div id="my_carousel" class="carousel slide"><!-- class of slide for animation -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div id="world_recipes" class="item active"><!-- class of active since it's the first item -->
              <div class="description">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
              </div>

              <div class="proj_image">
                <img src="http://placesheen.com/400/200">
              </div>

              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Caption text here</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->
          <!--  Next and Previous controls below -->
          <a class="carousel-control left" href="#my_carousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
          <a class="carousel-control right" href="#my_carousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
        </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily solve this by using inline positioning.

```
.description, .proj_image {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Note however that this solution requires a change to your DOM, as per [Css - two inline-block, width 50% elements don't stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6872020). The two blocks that you're inlining can't have whitespaces between them, as `inline-block` leaves that intact leading to undesired positioning of elements.

[See this Jsfiddle for a working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/UUthH/).

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the two child `div`s in a parent `div` that has a class of `clearfix`, make one `float: left;` and the other `float: right;`, and give both of them percentage-based widths that add up to 100.

Comment: This is a serious case of _divitis_. Not only that, a completely unnecessary use of floats.