# Inner div floating to next line

Tags: html, css

I was experimenting with div and trying to create a composite control using

1. Label
2. Text field

**HTML**

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-control {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.form-control[data-layoutOrder=horizontal] div[data-section=title] {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.form-control div[data-section=data] {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-control" data-layoutOrder="horizontal">
  <div data-section="title">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
  </div>
  <div data-section="data">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName">
  </div>
</div>
```

The output of the above code was expected to be label and input to be adjacent to each other, but thats not the case. The div wrapping text field is actually floating to next line, though I have set width of label div and textfield div to 50% using CSS.

[image: Div floating to next line]

I tried setting padding, margin etc to 0, but none of them worked. What is causing textfield div to float to the next line. When I changed one of the div's width to 49%, both divs got aligned on single line. I didn't understand as why it is behaving so?

Note: I could able to get both of them adjacent to each other using float property - `float:left` for label div & `float:right` property for textfield div. But I want to know as why setting 50% width didn't work without float. Do I really need to use float or am I missing something.

[image: Expected output]

EDIT 1: 
I found another solution by using `white-space` attribute as

```
.form-control {
background-color: yellow;
margin:0;
padding:0;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.form-control div[data-section=data] {
background-color : green;
display: inline-block;
width: 50%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
white-space:normal;
}
```

EDIT 2: Using `flex` style also has desired effect.
While searching more, I also came across achieving the same effect using `flex` style. Note that, it isn't supported in IE 10 and below. Refer [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

```
.form-control {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
}
.form-control[data-layoutOrder=horizontal] div[data-section=title] {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex:1;
}
.form-control div[data-section=data] {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  flex:1;
}
```

Comment: I suspect it's a border. Try setting border: 0; and outliine: 0; EDIT: I noticed now you have box-sizing, so that shouldn't be the case

Answer (score 2):

That's a tricky one. Inline-blocks elements will take count a new line in your HTML as a space, adding width to the total width of the elements. To fix it, add an empty HTML comment like this:

```
<div class="form-control" data-layoutOrder="horizontal">
    <div data-section="title">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    </div><!--
    --><div data-section="data">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName">
    </div>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/humwrgnj/

Comment: I edited your fiddle and removed the HTML comment. Nothing changed... Weird: I used the "tidy up" button and the layout got wrong again

Comment: @chiapa That is because the _TidyUp_ facility adds whitespace back in between the `div`s.

Comment: I can assure you that's the issue. Either add the html comment OR write the tags inline

Comment: Geez, these are some cool ninja tricks

Comment: The code will be bloated with too many comments. I don't think its appropriate.

Comment: That's why I rarely use inline-blocks. I usually go with floats but that was not your question, so I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply write the tags in one line

```
<div class="form-control" data-layoutOrder="horizontal">
    <div data-section="title">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    </div><div data-section="data">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName">
    </div>
    </div>
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-control {
 background-color: yellow;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.form-control[data-layoutOrder=horizontal] div[data-section=title]{
 display:inline-block;
 background-color : red;
 width: 50%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.form-control div[data-section=data] {
 background-color : green;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 50%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
```

```html
<div class="form-control" data-layoutOrder="horizontal">
<div data-section="title">
<label for="firstName">First Name</label>
</div><div data-section="data">
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cant use that, code formatter realigns everything.

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known issue with inline-block elements. The trick here is to use `font-size:0;` on your container element, and then override this in your child elements using `font-size:initial;`

Here's a quick demo:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-control {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size:0;
}
.form-control[data-layoutOrder=horizontal] div[data-section=title] {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size:initial;
}
.form-control div[data-section=data] {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size:initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-control" data-layoutOrder="horizontal">
  <div data-section="title">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
  </div>
  <div data-section="data">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

An alternative would be to use positioning if the element's are always going to be 50% width:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parent {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: tomato;
}
.childone {
  left: 0;
}
.childtwo {
  lefT: 50%;
  background: cornflowerblue;
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child childone"></div>
  <div class="child childtwo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is consistent with IE and chrome. So are you saying this is the issue with both the browsers? OR is there any mandate from W3C specification? Can you support the statement with online references.

Comment: @CuriousMind: there are already many [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262300/two-inline-block-elements-each-50-wide-do-not-fit-side-by-side-in-a-single-ro) stating such. [Again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871996/css-two-inline-block-width-50-elements-dont-stack), it's due to the whitespace. It's not an error, it's just 'how it is'

Comment: Setting font-size to `0` is horrible hack. That takes away capability of setting font-size to % for inner elements. The % are relative to parent elements font size.

Comment: I would never endorse using % font sizes. Use em units instead.

Comment: But if you're that set on using % font-size, then you could use my second answer.

Comment: I found another approach and that doesn't require too much of change in the code (check edit 1).

Comment: @CuriousMind: that may still require empty comments in your markup.

Comment: No it doesn't. Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS [float: left;](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) property to this class `.form-control[data-layoutOrder=horizontal] div[data-section=title]`

Comment: Well I already specified that in note of my question.