# Stack divs side by side without using float left

Tags: html, css

I want to stack `divs` ( 2 `divs` in 1 row )which are `50%` width **side by side** without using `float:left` because it will taken the `div` out of the normal flow. `Flexbox` is also not preferred because of limited browser support. How can I get the desired view without changing the width?

my code

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.col-content {
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <p class="col-content">
      col Item 1
    </p>
  </div>
 
  <div class="col">
    <p class="col-content">
      col Item 2
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col">
    <p class="col-content">
      col Item 3
    </p>
  </div>
 
  <div class="col">
    <p class="col-content">
      col Item 4
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean div will not go below another. You want horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: tried display inline?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871996/css-two-inline-block-width-50-elements-dont-stack and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628050/ignore-whitespace-in-html

Comment: @ketan Yes, div to be positioned sidewise. that is 2 divs in row. not below one another

Comment: @Webie i think sideroxylon given the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange but true - you can just remove the spaces between the elements from the HTML - like this:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
.col-content {
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <p class="col-content">
      col Item 1
    </p>
  </div><!--
 
  --><div class="col">
    <p class="col-content">
      col Item 2
    </p>
  </div><!--
  
   --><div class="col">
    <p class="col-content">
      col Item 3
    </p>
  </div><!--
 
   --><div class="col">
    <p class="col-content">
      col Item 4
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also try a margin of -4px on each inline-block element

Comment: Unorthodox way. but still working perfect. But Its seems the problem  will comeback  if I try to intent the HTML code.

Comment: It should be fine as long as the width of the inline blocks is half the width of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces between col div ending tag and starting tag.

**For Example:**

```
<div class="col">
    <p class="col-content">
      col Item 1
    </p>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <p class="col-content">
      col Item 2
    </p>
</div>
```

*to*

```
<div class="col">
    <p class="col-content">
      col Item 1
    </p>
</div><div class="col">
    <p class="col-content">
      col Item 2
    </p>
</div>
```

**Try this snippet:**

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.col-content {
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <p class="col-content">
      col Item 1
    </p>
  </div><div class="col">
    <p class="col-content">
      col Item 2
    </p>
  </div><div class="col">
    <p class="col-content">
      col Item 3
    </p>
  </div><div class="col">
    <p class="col-content">
      col Item 4
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want 2 divs in row.