# Putting 2 divs side by side with image+text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make 1 div with an image div and text below it, and beside it another one. Need it to be responsive later on.

For some reason making them 50% width makes them stack? I have to put them to 49.7%, and I don't know where the extra padding is coming from.

Here's what it is right now:

HTML:

```
<div class="center">
  <div class="home2">
    <div class="home2_first">
      <img src="Images/home_pic1.png" />
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text!</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="home2">
    <div class="home2_second">
      <img src="Images/home_pic2.png" />
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text!</p>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.home2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 49.7%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
}

.home2 p {
  font-family: 'cabinRegular', arial, sans-serif, verdana;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.home2_first img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.home2_second img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lq5vLdrm/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Solution would be to use  `display: block` and `float: left` or `float: right` instead.
   See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq5vLdrm/9/) here.
2. Use flexbox, which i would prefer: Just give the parent container:
   `display: flex; flex-flow: row;` and remove the `display: inline-block` property from it's children or set it to `display: block`. See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq5vLdrm/11/) here.
3. Do it in the good old fashioned way with table layout: `display: table` for parent and `display: table-cell` for children. See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq5vLdrm/12/) here.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed, I was adding the float to the wrong styles.

Answer (score 1):

An answer is found on multiple places on Stack Overflow, of which this one is accurate: [Two inline-block, width 50% elements wrap to second line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871996/css-two-inline-block-width-50-elements-dont-stack)

The issue appears because the `display: inline-block` property takes in account white-space in HTML.

A possible fix would be to remove the space between the closing tag of the first container and the opening tag of the second, like this:

```
</div><div class="home2">
```

Or you could place them like this:

```
</div><!--

--><div class="home2">
```

Comment: This worked as well, never knew about the inline-block taking the html white space into account, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume `display: inline-block` have lack of supporting the full container, perhaps you could add `float: left;` to your class `.home2` to supply a solid container. Then on your `@media` provide the desired width.

Here's the sample code.

```
.home2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
}
```