# Two div have width 50% and inline-block but still not in one line (no white space)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Here is my site :

```
<span class="field-content"><div class="field_home_team-wraper"><a href="/tran-dau/arsenal-vs-west-bromwich-albion-truc-tiep">  
      <h2>
      Arsenal

    </h2>
    <img src="/sites/default/files/styles/logo_150x150/public/2016-12/team_logo-2000x2000.png?itok=L_wkCsC6" width="150" height="150" alt="Arsenal logo" typeof="Image" class="image-style-logo-150x150">
</a></div><div class="versus-wraper">v</div><div class="field_away_team-wraper"><a href="/tran-dau/arsenal-vs-west-bromwich-albion-truc-tiep">
      <h2>
      West Brom

    </h2>

              <img src="/sites/default/files/styles/logo_150x150/public/2016-12/West_Bromwich_Albion.png?itok=vZlNXq8J" width="150" height="150" alt="West Bromwich Albion logo" typeof="Image" class="image-style-logo-150x150">
</a></div></span>
```

You can see 2 logo on top of site (div.field_home_team-wraper and .field_away_team-wraper), i want it stay in one line, so i set it width:50% and inline-block, so here is what i want to display:

[image: good]

But, **sometime** on PC browser and **alway** on iPhone browser, it will display like this :

[image]

I know there are white-space between two inline-block div, i removed it, you can look at source code to confirm. I don't know what problem here, please help.

Comment: 1) The .versus-wrapper also has a width; 2) try width 49% on both container

Comment: Add the css for the divs to your answer

Comment: Stack Overflow is not your personal debugger. We're trying to build a repository of good Q&As that will help people in the future. The absence of relevant code in your question makes it much less useful for the future (and that link will die at some point, which makes it useless too).

Comment: add css for a better response

Comment: Did you try white-space: nowrap;

Comment: @ppasler : .versus-wrapper is position: absolute, so it not in line, tried 49% and even 40%, still problem.

Comment: @GarretKaye : tried, but not work.

Comment: In which browsers does the issue occur?

Comment: @ppasler : Chrome on PC and Chrome&Safari on iPhone. On PC, most of time it display correcly, but sometime it wrong.

Comment: put width in percentage instead of pixel

Comment: @dreamhunter : width is 50%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My god, i solved this problem, just move div.versus-wraper to the last of span.field-content, everything become good.

But still don't know why it make a problem, still a mysterious with me. There are something to learn, if someone know, please answer.

Here is my question will more explain : [Browser image render break css inline-block layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41318507/browser-image-render-break-css-inline-block-layout)

Answer (score 0):

I just inspected the code on your site and I can't recreate the issue you're describing above. However, I did notice that there are a few lines of code that chrome isn't agreeing with - maybe try and resolve some of those issues to see if it fixes the problem on your end.

Comment: Thank you, what code is not good with chrome, can you explain more for me?

Comment: If you right click on the element you want to inspect (in this case, the element with the team logos) and click inspect. In the style window, you'll see a few rules that have caution signs beside them - those are the ones I'm referring to.

Answer (score -1):

This is a known bug.

`Display: Inline-Block`creates spaces between elements.

Here are two ways to fix this:

- First way, if you use `display: inline-block`, always use `margin-right: -4px` to fix the spaces between elements.
- Second way, use `font-size: 0` on parent `<div>` to remove spaces, and on elements inside `<div>` reset the font again to the size you want. Example: `font-size: 16px`

And another tip, be sure to use `Box-sizing: border-box`, so whatever if you put borders or margin or padding, doesn't affect the width in percentage...

Comment: I tried two ways you give me but still not work. The bug you say is this bug right ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871996/css-two-inline-block-width-50-elements-dont-stack

To solved spaces between elements, i'm already removed spaces in html.

Comment: Yes. Depending on your example given , there it's only the HTML without CSS, we can't really know the problem. I will try to Inspect your website with browser to see what really it's missing...

Comment: Have you tried using `border-box: box sizing;` on parent `<div>`?

Comment: I'm tried, not work. Other thing, Firefox display correctly.