# Browser image render break css inline-block layout

Tags: html, css, layout, browser, responsive-design

I have 2 div with 50% width and inline-block, on this div have a image. I'm expected  2 div will stay in one line, but sometime, browser break the layout.

Here is html :

```
<div class="views-field views-field-title">
    <span class="field-content">
    <div class="field_home_team-wraper"><a href="/tran-dau/arsenal-vs-west-bromwich-albion-truc-tiep"><h2>Arsenal</h2><img src="/sites/default/files/styles/logo_150x150/public/2016-12/team_logo-2000x2000.png?itok=L_wkCsC6" width="150" height="150" alt="Arsenal logo" typeof="Image" class="image-style-logo-150x150"></a></div><div class="versus-wraper">v</div><div class="field_away_team-wraper"><a href="/tran-dau/arsenal-vs-west-bromwich-albion-truc-tiep"><h2>West Brom</h2><img src="/sites/default/files/styles/logo_150x150/public/2016-12/West_Bromwich_Albion.png?itok=vZlNXq8J" width="150" height="150" alt="West Bromwich Albion logo" typeof="Image" class="image-style-logo-150x150"></a></div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here is css :

```
div.view-id-current_match_of_the_day div.views-field-title {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.view-id-current_match_of_the_day div.field_home_team-wraper, .view-id-current_match_of_the_day div.field_away_team-wraper {
    width: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.view-id-current_match_of_the_day div.field_home_team-wraper, .view-id-current_match_of_the_day div.field_away_team-wraper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.view-id-current_match_of_the_day div.field_home_team-wraper img, .view-id-current_match_of_the_day div.field_away_team-wraper img {
    width: 40%;
}

.view-id-current_match_of_the_day div.versus-wraper {
    width: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

As i say, I'm expected 2 div will stay in one line, like this :

[image]

But it not render correctly.

1. When first load, layout break to 2 lines like this:

[image]

Chrome on PC (*resize windows width less than 1024px for mobile responsive*) and Chromme on IOS/Android **have this problem**, Safari on IOS have this problem too.

Firefox, Edge on PC **not have problem**.

2. When click on homepage button or click something then go back to homepage, layout become render very good.

So i realize, at the first load (or refresh load), when browser requesting image to server, server not finished respone, browser already finished render the page, when image load finish, browser make a broken layout.

When second load (click on home page again), browser get the image from local cache, layout render is just good, correctly!

I record video here :

1. Chrome on PC (at 30 seconds, i press Ctrl+F5 for ignore cache reload) : https://streamable.com/8xpdx
2. Chrome on IOS : https://streamable.com/3bu5y

I can fix this if i add *float:left* to div.field_home_team-wraper and and div.field_away_team-wraper, but i need to avoid float in my css.

Another fix is remove div.versus-wraper, but i need this div and this div have absolute position, so it not in the line.

I aleady know there a space between 2 inline-block elements, so i **removed** space in my html : [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

I don't know what wrong here, please help.

Comment: [Re](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/5078297?noredirect=1#comment69849188_5078297): Hard to say what was wrong without a broken example, but it seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

My god, i solved this problem, just move div.versus-wraper to the last of span.field-content, everything become good.

But still don't know why it make a problem, still a mysterious with me. There are something to learn, if someone know, please answer.