# CSS Conditional Registration not working

Tags: css, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to register a conditional CSS for a SP2013 masterpage.

The thing is that it doesn't work at all: whatever the style I try to apply, the layout remains the same.

I've seen that I need to register the css that way:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration2" name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/style library/ie.css %&gt;" runat="server" after="custom.css" ConditionalExpression="IE 11" />
```

Actually I would like to apply this CSS for all IE versions, but as it wasn't working, I have just specified the version I'm using.

This `custom.css` is another CSS file that I have used and I registered the same way I'm trying to do with this one.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT should work properly as I dont see any issue in this.

Though you can have a look at this answer in a stack overflow, it may help you.

[How do I use Paul Irish's Conditional comments in a SharePoint 2010 master page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658113/how-do-i-use-paul-irishs-conditional-comments-in-a-sharepoint-2010-master-page)

Comment: Thank you for replying so quick! But I have taken a look in it before asking, but actually it hasn't been much help for me... I have tried as in the examples given in that post but the page remains exactly equal.

Comment: I've finally fixed this issue. I don't know how because I've just removed the attribute *after*, but the main thing is that I've succedeed it! Thank you very much! :)